# Why does my data save with symbols in my text file

Tags: c++, text-files

When I enter data and save it into my text file, its saving as symbols which i assume its binary. But i believe i don't have anything that has to do with binary. The image shows my output. Is there any mistake in my code that it makes my data save as binary in the text file?

```
void member::getdata()
{
        cout << "\tENTER ID (eg 200001): ";
        cin>> id;
        cout << "\tENTER NAME: ";
        cin>> name;
        cout << "\tENTER IC: ";
        cin>> ic;
        cout << "\tENTER AGE: ";
        cin>> age;
        cout << "\tENTER GENDER (F / M): ";
        cin>> gender;
        cout << "\tENTER POINTS: ";
        cin>> points;
        cout << "\tENTER TYPE MEMBERSHIP: ";
        cin>> membership;

}
void member::showdata() const
{
        cout<<"\nID of Member: "<< id;
        cout<<"\nName of Member: "<< name;
        cout<<"\nNRIC of Member: "<< ic;
        cout<<"\nAge of Member: "<< age;
        cout<<"\nGender of Member: "<< gender;
        cout<<"\nPoints of Member: "<< points;
        cout<<"\nType of Membership: "<< membership<<endl;

}
int main(){

    char ch;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
    cout<<setprecision(2); // program outputs decimal number to two decimal places
    intro();
    do
    {
        system("cls");

        cout<<"\n\n\t01. MAIN MENU ";
        cout<<"\n\n\t02. EXIT";

        cout<<"\n\n\tPlease Select Your Option (1 OR 2) ";
        cin>>ch;
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '1': entry_menu();
                break;
            case '2': entry_menu();
                break;
            default :cout<<"\a";
        }
    }
    while(ch!='2');
    return 0;
}

void write_member()
{
    member mem;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("NewMember.txt");
    mem.getdata();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&mem), sizeof(member));
    outFile.close();
    cout<<"\n\nMember record Has Been Created ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKQWX.png
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be in the file? You are reinterpret casting your `mem` object to a `char*` byte stream, that is certainly not a useful human readable format, that is generally for serialization/marshalling purposes.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of creating objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case, that means changing `ofstream outFile; outFile.open("NewMember.txt");` to `ofstream outFile("NewMember.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `outFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: All of the input is not checked for errors. Any or all of the reading could have failed and you could be printing uninitialized garbage.

Comment: I recommend removing option 2.  It's the same as option 1 (at least that's what the code says).

Comment: you need to read about de-/serialization. What you are doing is serialization without serialization. Writing the raw bytes to a file is sufficient to restore the object later only in rare cases

Comment: Where do you think the code is that converts the data from its internal binary format into a text format suitable for writing to a file? I don't see any code to do that.

Comment: I see no invocation of write_member(), this code can not compile.  Please review [MRE].

Comment: @CoryKramer Hi, can you explain a little more? What I should replace it with. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you are writing directly (i.e. not formatted) to the output stream with `outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&mem), sizeof(member));`. If you use this writing method it just copies all the bytes from your member into the file. If you want to output text that makes sense to read, just use the "<<" operator as you did with `std::cout`. This will write your member variables formatted into the text file. You can read more about it [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/). For example, numbers will be translated to numbers you can actually read:

> (1) arithmetic types
> Generates a sequence of characters with the representation of val, properly formatted according to the locale and other formatting settings selected in the stream, and inserts them into the output stream.

So to print your data structure I would suggest something like this:

```cpp
struct Member {
    std::uint32_t id;
    std::uint32_t points;
    std::string name;
    std::string gender;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Member& member) {
    out << "Member(";
    out << member.id << ", ";
    out << member.points << ", ";
    out << member.name << ", ";
    out << member.gender;
    return out << ")";
}

int main() {

    Member member = { 0, 10, "John", "male" };

    std::ofstream file("Test.txt");

    file << "binary: ";
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&member), sizeof(Member));
    file << "\n";
    file << "formatted: " << member;
    
}
```

produced text file (the part after "binary: " might be different):

```
binary:     
   ?k§  John ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              ÐJk§  male ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ              
formatted: Member(0, 10, John, male)
```

Comment: Hi, can you make it clear where am I supposed to add the '<<' operator? Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&member), sizeof(Member));` use the `<<` operator like suggested. If you specified `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Member& member)` you can just use `file << mem` instead. If not you have to print the member variables individually. We can't provide a full solution because you didn't provide important parts of your code in the question. However, the example I gave produces a file, which should make the usage very clear. Everything after "binary" is, well, binary and anything after "formatted" is readable text.